# how to use a 6v a/c adapter to run two 3v electric motors?

Tags: power-supply

I have my sons hot wheels track which runs on 4 size C cells        . I bought a 6v adapter so I could connect it to the battery pack but when I opened it up I realized there are two 3v motors run separately through a switch on two C batteries per motor.

Question is can I just split the positive and negative on the adapter into 2 positives and 2 negatives and run them directly to each motor ? or should I play it safer and connect the two 3V motors in series?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on the current draw of the motors an active rail splitter might work. (Sometimes called active virtual ground circuit)

Comment: Is the adapter 6V ac out, or 6V DC out? Are the batteries in series or parallel?

Comment: Adapter is 6v a/c out... batteries are in series 2xC batteries per motor but positive and negative from each pair of batteries are running to the on/off switch and then running to both 3v motors

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into half seams difficult to me, as the motors consume uniquely and unpredictable.

I would try to convert ([Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BHAOQO)) the 6V to 3V and connect the motors is parallel.

Answer (score 0):

**simple way:** connect motor in series.

**safer side:** use one voltage regulator(L7803) and connect both motor in parallel

Comment: Hi,so just connect the two motors in series and thats it ?

Comment: roger that and you can put one capacitor parallel with motor. For **safer side** use one voltage regulator(L7803) and connect both motor in parallel.

Comment: Is the capacitor 100% needed ?

Comment: as @Botnic said **motors consume uniquely and unpredictable** this capacitor will stabilize the motors at some extent.
i will highly recommend  to use voltage regulator(L7803) even it is not costly at all you will get around 0.15$

Answer (score 0):

Here the current consumption of motor have to be considered. Your adapter should have more than 1A rating since we are not clear with the 3V motor max load current rating. 
And after all this if you are sure you can use LM1117-N Voltage regulator and connect the motors in parallel.